# Kendo Grid Conditional Destroy and Show Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid, when user clicks delete button
the controller must make some operations. According to this operations,
data will not be deleted then should Show a message like 'you can not delete this record'
How to do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<teknik.Models.Magaza_Viewmodel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Visible(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.NAME);
    columns.Command(command => { 
        command.Edit(); 
        command.Destroy();
    });
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("TmpMagaza").CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID) )
    .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "Home"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Home"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("Destroy", "Home"))
    )
```

)

controller Destroy Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Magaza_Viewmodel magaza)
    {
        if (magaza != null)
        {
            if (!valid) {
                // record not deleted, show message
            }
            else
            {
                magazaModel.Destroy(magaza);
            }
        }
        return Json(new[] { magaza }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be to hide the commands that the user does not have access to.  I would create another column, but then use client template to determine what is said within the column.  Client template allows for you to use javascript by placing it within '#' characters, so that is where you can include conditional statements. The html could then call the same action that the Destroy command would have called.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Visible(false);
columns.Bound(p => p.NAME);
columns.Command(command =>command.Edit());
columns.Bound(p =>p.ID).ClientTemplate("#if(condition){#html1#}#");
```